# getting problem starting serving new project Angular

Tags: angular

I create a new Angular project and install packages. When I serves the project, the server gives me module build failure as shown in the this image.

[image: Server Console Log]

I try to re-install angular-cli and node, and then terminate all projects on the server but I still get the same error. In addition, I see a HTTP 404 error in the browser console, as shown in the following image.

[image: Browser Console Log]

I don't what the problem is, as the project is newly created. I hope someone can help me.

A screen capture of the package.json is in the next diagram.

[image: Package.json]

Comment: include steps to reproduce, node version, and angular cli version

Comment: Angular CLI: 16.1.3
Node: 18.16.1

Comment: can you share your package.json as well?

Comment: i uploaded package.json photo @CanGeylan

Comment: i think a package that angular's peer dependencies is causing the issue. i would check angular github for updates, cause it's a global issue that we're also having at our company at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is fixed by angular. delete node_modules and do a fresh npm install